# App unavailable in my country, even though it clearly is

Tags: google-play-store, downloading

Quick question.
How is it that my boss is able to download Pokemon go on his Samsung Galaxy S7. We both have phones tied to the company, he is sitting next to me (both in the UK), but when I attempt to download the game through google play it says it's not available in my country.

I've had it running (uninstalled now) from an unsigned APK (apkmirror) since last week. Also, the creditcard tied to my google play account is Swedish - not sure if that could make any sort of a difference...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Download and install Hotspot Shield to your mobile via play store .Then run hotspot shield and try downloading the app.In case this method does not work you can first check where pokemon go is available and you can download the VPN for the same country and run the game.

Comment: I shouldn't have to do that? I mean if I sit right next to my boss, who is using the same type of phone under the exact same contract surely the play store should recognize that I'm in the same country? :p

Comment: but its not you should get your mobile fixed or use these ways